# Deselect all selected rows in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm using jQuery Datatables plugin (v 1.10)

I am using the select feature and can highlight/select rows fine. I'm also using paging. I can page through the tables and select on multiple pages. I tried to create a button to clear selected rows, but it only clears rows selected on the current page.

Like this: `$('#main_index1 tbody tr').removeClass('selected');`

For example, if I have a row selected on page 1 and then go to page 2 of the table and run this function, the row selected on page 1 isn't deselected. If I selected something on page 2, that deselects just fine.

Any ideas how to deselect all selected rows across all pages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured this out...tried this instead:

```
table = $("#main_index1").DataTable();
table 
    .rows( '.selected' )
    .nodes()
    .to$() 
    .removeClass( 'selected' );
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: The following would work too if you use Select extension `table.rows( { selected: true } ).deselect()`

Comment: deselect did not work for me. This worked. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

This is not mine. Found it on the Internet. But it works like a charm:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
table.rows().deselect();
```

Answer (score 0):

`.deselect()` or

```
table = $("#main_index1").DataTable();
table 
    .rows( '.selected' )
    .nodes()
    .to$() 
    .removeClass( 'selected' ); did not work for me.
```

I did the following change and it worked. I had to explicitly set the checked property to false.

```
var rows = table.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
$('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this via **Tabletools.js** plugin

Get the tabletool instance of the actual table:

```
var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance('file-records');
```

oTT now supports various methods for datatable:

```
oTT.fnSelectNone();
```

`fnSelectNone()` deselects all rows (previously selected) across every page

Comment: We can learn something new, if you mention the reason for downvote.

Comment: Can't describe others' reasons for voting, but this deviates from topic by introducing TableTools when the question concerned DataTables.  It's like if someone asks "How do I do X in Drupal?" and the response is "You can do that in Joomla" - nice to know but not a helpful answer in context.  Might better serve as a comment.

Comment: Well TableTools.js is a plug-in for the DataTables ,which is useful for resolving the issue  asked in the question.
anyways i will try to restrict my answer to the topic hereon.
Thanks for the feedback..Cheers ..!

Comment: That's a fair response.  I forgot there was a TableTools extension; keep in mind that extension has been retired.